# Is it possible to extend bpy.types.ID?

Tags: data-blocks

I've been working on an exporter script which contains a collection of tools for describing game-specific objects which are to be exported. Right now i've been doing a custom PropertyGroup defining a particle system, linking it to objects by doing this:

```
bpy.types.Object.mdl_emitter = PointerProperty(type=MDLParticleEmitter)
```

The problem is that first of all, this attaches the data to all objects, which is not what i want. I want there to be a button to press which creates it, and preferably, i'd want there to be a scene-wide collection of particle systems similar to how it already works with things like materials, so that multiple objects can have a reference to the same data. I know that bpy.types.ID is the base of most such classes, and i wonder if it's possible to simply extend it, whether the garbage collection/fake user features would still work for them out of the box, and what the best practice would be for storing them in the scene.